# How to assign array into an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to assign value to a object property through loops.

I have something like

```
 var data = {'item1' : 'aa', 'item2' : 'bb', 'item3' : 'cc' ..more};
 var elements: [
               {
                 type : 'html',
                 html : 'adding html'
               },
               {
                 type:'select',
                 id:'select box',
                 //I want to add all my data array below but not sure how to do it.
                 items: [[data['item1'],0],[data['item2'],0]]
               }
              ]
```

I am not sure how to apply loop inside the element object. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Comment: `data` looks like you started writing javascript and ended using php. What is that supposed to be? JS doesn't have associative arrays like that. Really...none of your code makes any sense.

Comment: If this is JS then `data` should be defined like this: `var data = {'item1' : 'aa', 'item2' : 'bb', 'item3' : 'cc' ..more};`

Comment: What is stopping you from doing `items: data`? Then you have access to `data` and you can manipulate it later.

Comment: @m59 sorry my bad. I got them mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this (requires JavaScript 1.8.5):

```
var elements = [
    {
        type : 'html',
        html : 'adding html'
    },
    {
        type:'select',
        id:'select box',
        items: Object.keys(data).map(function(key) { return [ data[key], 0 ]; })
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

to assign from a loop

```
var items= new Array();
for ( /* loop sttings depending on how you'll do it, and we suppose i as counter */){
   var obj: new Object();
   // set object feilds and values
   items.push(obj);
}
```

and to get the elements :

```
for (i in elements){
   variable = items[i].feild;
   // or var obj = items[i];
}
```

Comment: -1: What does this even do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it while you're defining `elements` object.
Just define `items` as an array, like this: `items : []` 
Then

```
var index = 0;
for (var element in data) {
    items[index++] = [data[element], 0];
}
```